# TO Update URL attributes In xmlfile using fileuploadcontrol

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have an XMLFile.xml
like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
<pdf ID="121">

 <URL>www.google.co.in</URL>
 </pdf>
</items>
```

i have fileupload control that have path.when i click on save it change the URL attributes with respect to that ID..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {


    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));


    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            //string file = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
            Label1.Text = filepath;
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/items/pdf[@ID='121']");
            // update MainCategory 
            nodeList[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText = Label1.Text;


            // Don't forget to save the file
            xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
            Response.Write("XML File updated!");
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following   error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
   }
```